# How is called DTO class that also access db?

Tags: c#, .net, dto

The definition of [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) from Wikipedia is the following:

*Data transfer object (DTO) is an object that carries data between processes.
The difference between data transfer objects and business objects or data access objects is that a **DTO does not have any behavior except for storage and retrieval of its own data** (accessors and mutators). DTOs are simple objects that should not contain any business logic that would require testing.*

If, instead, the class containing the Data is not used for data transfer and has also the methods for CRUD operation which should be the acronym of that kind of class?

Comment: "Bad design". It validates the SOLID principle. I would call the term of Wikipedia broken in this regard. DTO's are transfer objects and should not have storage and retrieval behavior. THat is what a repository is for.

Comment: `TightlyCoupled` or `DoNotDoThis` class ?

Comment: @TomTom: But there isn't a name for this kind of Design? I've also edited the question. Now it's more clear

Comment: @Revious "YouArefiredDtoPattern". Good enough? DTO's are transfer objects, they should not contain any access logic.

Comment: "which should be the acronym of that kind of class" SMH? OMG? DTM (DoingTooMuch)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [Active Records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record).

And it's indeed a very bad idea using it, as explained [about everywhere](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/70309).